# Invalid `Podfile` file: 767: unexpected token at 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'configurations'

Tags: ios, react-native, podspec

Im getting this error whenever im trying to hit arch -x86_64 pod install in my mac m1 chip

[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: 767: unexpected token at 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'configurations')

```
at Object.dependencyConfig (/Users/qs033/Documents/locateBeeNewProject/LocateBee/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/config/index.js:102:37)

at /Users/qs033/Documents/locateBeeNewProject/LocateBee/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-config/build/loadConfig.js:35:61

at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)

at getDependencyConfig (/Users/qs033/Documents/locateBeeNewProject/LocateBee/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-config/build/loadConfig.js:31:51)

at get @mapbox/mapbox-sdk [as @mapbox/mapbox-sdk] (/Users/qs033/Documents/locateBeeNewProject/LocateBee/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-config/build/loadConfig.js:79:20)

at /Users/qs033/Documents/locateBeeNewProject/LocateBee/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-config/build/commands/config.js:15:51

at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)

at filterConfig (/Users/qs033/Documents/locateBeeNewProject/LocateBee/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-config/build/commands/config.js:14:38)

at Object.func (/Users/qs033/Documents/locateBeeNewProject/LocateBee/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-config/build/commands/config.js:25:32)

at Command.handleAction (/Users/qs033/Documents/locateBeeNewProject/LocateBee/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:108:23)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
'.

## from /Users/qs033/Documents/locateBeeNewProject/LocateBee/ios/Podfile:8

## -------------------------------------------

## target 'LocateBee' do

> config = use_native_modules!

## -------------------------------------------

Comment: It will be much helpful if you share your target pod file.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?  facing the exact same issue